# How to do SQL Query for XML data (in SQLServer)?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xsd, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table called tblFiles in SQL Server 2008 R2.

tblFiles as the following columns:

1. FileId - (int) primary key
2. FileName - (nvarchar 255)
3. MetaData - (xml) has been configured with an XML schema for
   validation.

The schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FileMetaData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CreatedDate" type="xs:time"/>
                <xs:element name="ModifiedDate" type="xs:time"/>
                <xs:element name="AccessDate" type="xs:time"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Length" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A sample XML metadata entry in a record is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FileMetaData Length="26">
    <CreatedDate>10:13:53.1008</CreatedDate>
    <ModifiedDate>10:14:02.0327</ModifiedDate>
    <AccessDate>10:13:53.1008</AccessDate>
</FileMetaData>
```

I've populated the database with a load of files and its associated metadata.

What I'm trying to work out is how to write a query that will return return all records that have a length set in the XML that is between X and Y?

How do I navigate the XML in the SQL query?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this on your XML:

```
SELECT MyXmlCol.value('(/FileMetaData/@Length)[1]', 'int')
FROM MyXmlTable
WHERE MyXmlCol.value('(/FileMetaData/@Length)[1]', 'int') BETWEEN 25 AND 30
```

Output:

```
26
```

You have to remember the [1] to tell the query to grab the first value.  The "@" specifies an XML attribute.  You can check out the docs on the value() function here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx

Comment: I managed to figure out another way to do this as well using the query:
SELECT FileId, FileName, MetaData 
FROM Files 
WHERE MetaData.exist('/FileMetaData[@Length > 25]') = 1 AND MetaData.exist('/FileMetaData[@Length < 30]') = 1

I have tried both methods but the one I listed here has much better performance (BTW I have an XML index on the column MetaData).

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory, so my syntax might be a little out. It should be something like this:

```
declare @x int
declare @y int

set @x = 10
set @y = 50

select *
from tblFiles
where MetaData.value('(/FileMetaData/@Length)', 'int') between @x and @y
```

There are plenty of other SO questions on this kind of topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966441/xml-query-in-sql-server-2008
- [Best way to search in data stored as XML in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945/best-way-to-search-data-stored-as-xml-in-sql-server)